# Is there anyway to get a free driver for an old keyboard?

Tags: drivers

I have tried several sites but they all give you the scan for free then want to charge you.  I was given a Mitsumi keyboard & cannot get it to work on my laptop.

Comment: What is so special about this keyboard that you need a driver for it?

Comment: A model number would be nice also.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have something like the Mitsumi Millennium and need something to drive the hotkeys.

> 15 keyboard shortcuts allow you to do a single keystroke, where normally takes a few mouse clicks - if you turn off your computer, connect to the Internet, run applications, etc

I Googled for Mitsumi drivers but nothing useful came up.

You may want to Google a bit harder, or if you're SOL I think you could use software like AutoHotKey to customise the hotkeys.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [**DriverMax**](http://www.drivermax.com/), they offer old drivers and such for Windows XP, Vista, & 7, and allow you to download a limited number of drivers per day, free.